# Reverse SSH tunnel on the iPad

Tags: ios, network, ssh, tunnel

Is is possible to set up a reverse SSH tunnel on an iPad?

I'd like to be to do basic nmap TCP scans and use some other tools that the iPad doesn't have on remote networks.  So my idea is after I've connected to the network, ssh to my home server.  Then from my home server ssh back onto my iPad.

Are there any apps out there that provide this functionality?  Is it possible without jailbreaking?  Or is there an even simpler solution that I'm missing?

Comment: What have you already tried? What specific goal do you have in mind (for which you think this is the ideal solution)?

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to ssh in to any iDevice without jailbreaking. (If I were just a tiny bit more confident about this, I'd post that as an answer.)

Answer (score 1):

> So my idea is after I've connected to the network, ssh to my home server.

For SSH into a remote server you can use many apps available on the App Store. My favorite one is [Prompt](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prompt/id421507115?mt=8).

> Then from my home server ssh back onto my iPad.

You can't SSH into an iOS device without jailbreaking (unless you are an Apple engineer). You would need to [jailbreak first](http://jailbrea.kr) and then install the OpenSSH package from Cydia.

> Or is there an even simpler solution that I'm missing?

Why do you need to SSH into your home server if you're just using it to get into the iPad?  Seems like a lot of trouble, and you might need to mess around with port forwarding on the iPad's network.

SSHing into the iPad by connecting to localhost should do the trick. I assume you've jailbroken and installed all the utilities you need onto the iPad. Shouldn't be too bad as it looks like they're all open-source programs and you can recompile them if you really need to.