# Can Safari (iPad iOS 12.4.2) be configured to utilize SSH-Tunnel / Port Forwarding?

Tags: ios, ssh, tunnel

Goal: from WAN, SSH-tunnel to home router (outfitted with SSH) and access **remote** LAN devices with iPad's web browser.

As I understand it, a SSH-tunnel (connection) must be established first, which I imagine would require an App?  The [Ubuntu equivalent](https://www.tecmint.com/create-ssh-tunneling-port-forwarding-in-linux/) being:

```
ssh -f -N admin@server1.example.com -L 8080: server1.example.com:3000
```

Unless the app routes all web browser (port 80?) traffic through its tunnel, then there would need to be a setting in the browser that enable a tunnel proxy?

What are today's options? Solution preference is for simplicity & low-cost.  Simplicity comprises avoiding jail-break.

Comment: Avoiding jailbreak is a good idea for many - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58386/reverse-ssh-tunnel-on-the-ipad

Answer (score 1):

I don’t recommend using software for ssh tunnels since it’s less efficient than a VPN connection, but here are a list of software and options:

- [Which options exist for SSH tunneling clients on iOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69163/whats-a-good-ssh-tunneling-client-for-ios)

Apple doesn't enable an sshd process on iOS so you'll need to alter or add software to accomplish this if you can't just set up a web proxy in the cloud or on a more traditional server and point your iOS device to that web proxy or ssh tunnel on an OS that presumes wall power.